# Using delegatecall for multiple parameters fuction in solidity

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

Does someone have a exemple of solidity delegatecall for multiple parameters function?

Comment: please very please

Comment: Could you give us an example of the function,  so I can write specific delegate call that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. The function we are calling has the abi of `transferFrom(address,address,uint256)`

```
function deletageCallMultiple(address contract) external {
    (bool success, bytes memory data) = contract.delegateCall(abi.encodeWithSignature("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)", 0xf9e3975073d6969201d95bc1d2709a71347dd83e, 0x51636eecd2d95efb5a82cb3c73634e2aab68f6a8, 438);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stick to my example. Delegatecalls cannot return values. Example:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

contract ContractD {
    address public contract_e_address;

    constructor(address _contract_e_address) public {
        contract_e_address = _contract_e_address;
    }

    function invokeContractE(uint256 _number_1, uint256 _number_2) public { 
        ContractE e = ContractE(contract_e_address);
        e.setN(_number_1, _number_2);
    } 
}

contract ContractE {
    uint256 public number_1;
    uint256 public number_2;

    function setN(uint256 _number_1, uint256 _number_2) public {
        number_1 = _number_1;
        number_2 = _number_2;
    }
}
```

**OR**

If ContractE is already running on the blockchain for some time you can call it as interface in the contract you are about to deploy. Example:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

contract ContractD {
    ContractE e = ContractE(<CONTRACT_E_ADDRESS>);

    function invokeContractE(uint256 _number_1, uint256 _number_2) public { 
        e.setN(_number_1, _number_2);
    } 
}

interface ContractE {
    function setN(uint256 _number_1, uint256 _number_2) external;
}
```

Comment: not relevant. OP is asking about calling a function with multiple parameters

Comment: Actually it is totally relevant, because in both of the examples method ```setN``` is called by passing 2 parameters ( which means both examples are with multiple parameters ). Also have in mind that the examples are written 2019 by using ```pragma solidity 0.5.10;```. If you're using different version then you might experience issues.