# How to call the super contract function where msg.sender should be same in solidity?

Tags: abi, solidity-0.5.x, keccak, delegatecall

I am trying to call contract A.fun_A() via Contract C

```js
contract A{
   function fun_A(address tenant, uint itemId){
     //Here the msg.sender should be msg.sender in C
     require(msg.sender == ownerOf(itemId));
     ....
   }
}

contract B is A{
    ...
}

contract C {
    B contract_B;
    constructor(address deployer_B){
        contract_B = B(deployer_B);
    }

    function fun_A(address tenant, uint itemId){
       //-------???? How to invoke fun_A where msg.sender should be same as in C
    }
}
```

Try 1:

```py
(bool status1, bytes memory data1) = address(contract_B)
     .delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("fun_A(address, uint256)")), tenant, itemId));
```

Try 2:

```java
(bool status1, bytes memory data1) = address(contract_B)
      .delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("fun_A(address, uint256)", tenant, itemId));
```

Both didnt work.. I would like to invoke the inheritated functions through child contract where msg.sender should be same as in Contract C. is there any other way to pass address as an argument via delegatecall?

Update:

Thanks. removed space yet didnt solved. that did worked for the function in contract B.. but its not making call to the function in contract A.

https://gist.github.com/Kowsi/147cf728ec0da29bfbd9c7a5977b7d2c#file-dealerlessmarket-sol .. Line 123 is working fine.. Line 126 & 137 are not working.. Here I am trying to implement ERCX - ERC2615

Comment: Take a look at the answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76863/using-delegatecall-for-multiple-parameters-fuction-in-solidity/76870#76870 . It might help you.

Comment: Get rid of the space in `address, uint256`.

Comment: As you can learn from [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/abi-spec.html?highlight=selector#function-selector): "Parameter types are split by a single comma - no spaces are used".

Comment: BTW, this is exactly the same as [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/86856/16043).

Comment: Thanks. that did worked for the function in contract B.. but its not making call to the function in contract A

Comment: @jiswok What does `approveTenantRight` do? Does it access A's storage? Delegatecall opcode doesn't change storage so it will keep accessing C's storage as it were A.

Comment: I am not sure about storage.. Here is the [link](https://github.com/kohshiba/ERC-X/blob/master/contracts/ERCX/Contract/ERCX.sol#L280) to that function ..

Comment: @jiswok It does access storage through `_tenantRightApprovals`, so you cannot call that function using delegatecall. Delegatcall cannot be used to impersonate or to act on behalf msg.sender.

Comment: Is there any solution that fix this issue?

Comment: @jiswok It works in that way by design. If you control A contract you call the method directly and pass the msg.sender as parameter (you will need to secure the call so it can't be abused).